# Are these sentences grammatically correct?

Tags: tense, grammaticality

I made the sentences; there's no source.

> If he would do this, it would be easy for him.
>
> If he would have done this, it would have been easy for him.
>
> If he had done it, it would going to be easy for him.

I am asking the usage of tenses and verbs here.

Edit:Second version of 3rd sentence:

> *If he had done it, it would be going to be easy for him. *

Is this one correct?

Comment: You might like to check out [“If I would have lost you” vs “If I had lost you”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62482/) over on ELU. Note that many native speakers (myself included) really don't like fully-enunciated ***he would have*** in your example #2 (we're okay with contracted ***he'd have*** or ***he'd 've***, but in practice basic Past Perfect ***If he had done it*** or ***If he'd done it*** are probably more likely. By the way, your example #3 is completely invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, in conditional type 2 that indicates an  unreal or imaginary  situation, you use the past tense in the if-clause, and would + infinitive in the main clause. For example:

If he did this, it would be easy for him.

But, sometimes, you also use the subjunctive  would + infinitive  in the if-clause to show willingness to do something on the part of the subject of the if-clause.

If he would do this, it would be easy for him.

The speaker of the sentence implies that he is not willing to this, so it won't be easy for him.

The second sentence in the conditional type 3 should be formed as follows:

If he had done this, it would have been easy for him.

As for the third sentence, it's completely incorrect; you don't use -ing form immediately after the modal would.

Regarding the sentence 'If he had done this, it would be going to be easy for him', it's correct grammatically.  It is a mixed type 3 and type 2 conditional.  It implies that he didn't do this, so it's not going to be easy for him.

Comment: another version of 3rd part is added,is that correct?

Comment: Yes, it's OK, Bhai.

Comment: Do your 'If he had done this, it would have been easy for him.' should have would have instead of had?Because would have is a possibility but had is surety.

Comment: Bhai, you cannot do so. In the conditional type 3 that's hypothetical or contrafactual,  you use had + past participle in the if-clause. Moreover, the use of if doesn't indicate that something will definitely happen.